# Динамические формы

Tags: javascript, html

День добрый.

Есть вопрос по javascript. Уверен, для знатоков здесь все просто. Опишу суть задачи.
Кусок кода формы:

```
<tr>
<td>
<select name="tovar1">
<option value="1">sklad1</option>
<option value="2">sklad2</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
Цена: 1000
</td>
</tr>
```

В БД для каждого товара (tovar1) есть несколько цен в зависимости от склада (sklad1, sklad2). Нужно, чтобы в зависимости от выбора склада для данного товара динамически менялось поле "цена". Грубо говоря, мы переключаем склады в теге select и цена меняется на нужную. как в примере, для 1го склада - цена 1000, для второго - 1500.

Дело еще в том, что на генерируемой странице будет много таких товаров, соотв. изменение каждого select'a должно отражаться на соответствующем изменении текста.

Если можно, приведите пример для нескольких позиций. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Наивный" способ. =)

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select name="tovar123" onchange="chPrice(123, this.value)">
            <option value="10">sklad1</option>
            <option value="11">sklad2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td id="prices123">
        Цена:
        <span id="price123_10" class="price">1000</span>
        <span id="price123_11" class="price" style="display:none">1500</span>
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
function chPrice(pid, sid){
    var s = document.getElementById('prices'+pid).getElementsByTagName('span');
    for(i = 0, il = s.length; i < il; ++i){
        if(/price/.test(s[i].className)){
            s[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('price'+pid+'_'+sid).style.display = '';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Соррь а зачем скрытие поля?? и тд.
если у него там миллион складов???

Comment: Ну не ajax'ом же.  
Можно задать атрибутом в option.

Comment: мой вариант ниже, просто с value опции вытаскивать. но суть вопроса другая) почему ты воспользовался скрытыми полями??? это просто предпочтение или в этом есть какой прикол?

Comment: Как я понял, значение в select'ах надо сохранить для добавления товаров в корзину, например. Поэтому значение надо размещать либо в атрибуте, либо в теге. Мне больше нравится работать со статическим контентом.

Comment: а) спс за ответ)

Comment: пробую второй вариант (через span), но не работает :(

Comment: первый вариант, к сожалению не подходит (по крайней мере в данном виде), т.к. после submit мне нужно передать также выбранный склад, т.е. его ID, а в этом варианте поле option value принимает значение цены товара на этом складе. В самой форме цену передавать скрипту не нужно, она вычислится на стороне сервера.

Comment: function chPrice(pid, sid){
    var s = document.getElementById('prices'+pid).getElementsByTagName('span');
    alert (s.length); ////////// trace var lengh
    for(i = 0, il = s.length; i < il; ++i){
        if(/price/.test(s[i].className)){
            s[i].style.dispay = 'none';
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('price'+pid+'_'+sid).style.dispay = '';
}

alert выдает 0 :(

Comment: коллеги, плз хелп!

Comment: Прошу прощения, допустил ошибку в слове display. Обновил код.

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr>

 <td>
  <select onchange='changePrice(this)' name="tovar1">
   <option value="1000">sklad1</option>
   <option value="1001">sklad2</option>
  </select>
 </td>

 <td>
  Цена: <span id='price'>1000</span>
 </td>

</tr>

function changePrice(obj){
  var price = obj.value;
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = price;
}
```

Comment: Проблема решена.
Итак, было 2 проблемы:
1. Как оказалось, нужно было прописать
   var s = document.getElementById('prices'+pid).document.getElementsByTagName('span');
   вместо
   var s = document.getElementById('prices'+pid).getElementsByTagName('span');
2. Не смейтесь сильно, но 2 часа убил на поиск решения проблемы. Дело в том, что в тексте была описка и вместо
   s[i].style.display = 'none';
   стояло
   s[i].style.dispay = 'none';
   (и еще в одном месте)
Но за помощь, конечно, спасибо!
P.S. За основу взял 2й вариант, автора ling, за что ему огромное спасибо.

Comment: Поспешил я с выводами :(
Работает только в IE. Хром, ФФ, Опера - напрочь отказываются исполнять скрипт. Более того, bugZilla выдает ошибку document.getElementById("prices" + pid) is null
В чем может быть проблема?